# Noob web developer wants to add web design and interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, django

I'm sure this question has been asked but it's hard to just google specifically for what i'm looking for.

So, basically I'm already comfortable with OOP and computer science from college material. Now, I'm trying to learn web development and already have the basics of HTML, CSS, and some django (which is what I'm using to make the website).

Now, I know CSS is for kind of designing how the website looks. And javascript can help add animations and extra stuff. Then I've heard so much more stuff like AJAX and javascript (maybe someone could help give me a list of all the tools that are for design: AJAX, javascript, javascript libraries, etc.).

Basically, my main question is this: **Anyone have any recommendations for how I should approach learning this material?**

(Like, should I try to pick up javascript and learn some of the libraries that are often used? or... maybe I have the wrong idea of what javascript does)

EDIT: So it's been over a year since I've been doing web development at a job. I learned the basics and that post I marked as the answer has defnitely been helpful. But now, I feel like the best way to learn ANYTHING in terms of making a web is to throw your ideas all into your head and then google to understand what tools you can look for and use to materialize those ideas. For example, my post was about "web design and interaction." As a web developer, that's not my job so obviously something like twitter bootstrap helps. But there's also other front-end plugins and tools, it's helped me just to google and look them up to find what I want done. I feel like that's the best way to approach "learning this material"

Comment: w3schools has some stuff which you may like.

Comment: [Friends don't let friends use w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: hehe, i like this site for html and css better. http://htmldog.com/guides/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For learning Javascript (and a few other languages), I'd suggest [Codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0).

AJAX is just a way of using JavaScript to load content or changes dyanmically.

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is the most popular JavaScript library, which, if you already know CSS selectors, can be quite easy to get to grips to as they have a very useful [api](http://api.jquery.com/) library.

Following web blogs such as [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) and [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) is very useful, as they offer tips and solutions, and just generally make the web industry exciting.

Edit:

The standard starting points for building a website are:

[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) - A great blank starting plate that offers a very optimised blueprint, with lots of fixes of known browser bugs and tips.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) - Similair to HTML5 boilerplate, and most people use a mix of both, this bootstrap is a great way to get a website together quickly, and has options for making it [responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design).

It really depends how you find best to learn, personally I like to get all the basics learnt through video tutorials, and then just push myself with my own projects, and just research when I hit a brick wall.

I'd say for a good starting point [TutsPlus](https://tutsplus.com/) have some very good tutorials, in particular:
[30 days to learn jQuery](https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/)
[PHP Fundamentals](https://tutsplus.com/course/php-fundamentals/)
[Generally any of their courses to be honest](https://tutsplus.com/courses/)

If you fancy an all-in-one solution - [TeamTreehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/) are great.

Comment: so I guess just go searching and looking around is fine. and use the javascript library to add flair and extra functionality to a site? is there any other umm.. tool, library, or framework for website design that I should know about? thanks btw

Comment: I've updated my post with some extra links I've thought of.

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://w3schools.com/ they have great tutorials for beginners in the areas you have mentioned and more.

The interactive tutorials on Code Academy are great
HTML/CSS: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web
JavaScript: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript-upgraded

Hope these help.

Good luck getting into Web Development.

Comment: please don't recommend w3schools. Reasons: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: w3schools can be a helpful resource to start out with to get the basics, its how I started out. I would not recommend getting their certifications (not that I have myself but they are a waste), but the content in the various pages can be helpful for beginners wanting an introduction to the various web technologies.